# Podman missing health check

Tags: docker, podman, health-check

i have an image that is based on an image with health check. In my case its the oracle database image `container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe`.

However, **when I build my image with podman, it no longer contains the health check** that it should inherit from the base image.

You can see the layer when you look into the image with `podman history` (see below). But neither podman nor docker show a health state when you create a container from this image.

The strange thing is that **it works as intended when the image is build with docker** instead of podman. I would expect it to make no difference whether it is build by podman or docker.

```
$ podman history bebfa0c3dc0f
ID            CREATED        CREATED BY                                     SIZE        COMMENT
bebfa0c3dc0f  44 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:312dcb9c3445e73...  131 kB      FROM my-image
...
<missing>     9 months ago   HEALTHCHECK &{["CMD-SHELL" "\"$ORACLE_BASE...  0 B         buildkit.dockerfile.v0
...
```

Comment: What version of podman are you using?

Comment: Currently on podman version 4.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When building an image that has a `HEALTHCHECK` using Podman 4.4.1, I receive the warning:

```
WARN[0000] HEALTHCHECK is not supported for OCI image format and will be ignored. Must use `docker` format
```

If I add `--format docker` it builds without a warning, and the healthcheck works as expected.